# Does anyone know how to create a new database (through code) on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku

I'm confronted with a large number of clients all doing large number of transactions on distinct record sets. 
I have say 100 clients each with 500k product records. 
Previously I had separated their data with different schemas. It worked fine for a small time then we noticed that when one client was hammering the database all others would grind to a halt.

We then moved to separate instances of Heroku.  Each client had their own application and thus their own database.  The problem with this is that on-boarding a new client means we have to fire up a new Heroku app and typically that task falls to a developer.

Ok.. so that's the background.
Now my question.  I want to create a new database on Heroku for each client.  (all in one "application"). When we on-board a new client my app will create the database and tie the username to that database. 
I can create a database readily enough with something like this.

```
heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:#{db_plan}
```

But what I don't know is how to get the username and password for this new database, so I can store it against the new user.

QUESTION:  How does one get the user name and password for a database they created on heroku?

Answer (score 1):

the heroku toolbelt has a pg:credentials option, I've never tried what you're attempting, but it's possible you can obtain that information here.

```
Usage: heroku pg

 List databases for an app

Additional commands, type "heroku help COMMAND" for more details:

  pg:credentials DATABASE                                   #  Display the DATABASE credentials.
  pg:info [DATABASE]                                        #
  pg:kill procpid [DATABASE]                                #  kill a query
  pg:killall [DATABASE]                                     #  terminates ALL connections
  pg:promote DATABASE                                       #  Sets DATABASE as your DATABASE_URL
  pg:ps [DATABASE]                                          #  view active queries with execution time
  pg:psql [DATABASE]                                        #
  pg:pull <REMOTE_SOURCE_DATABASE> <LOCAL_TARGET_DATABASE>  #  Pull from REMOTE_SOURCE_DATABASE to LOCAL_TARGET_DATABASE
  pg:push <LOCAL_SOURCE_DATABASE> <REMOTE_TARGET_DATABASE>  #  Push from LOCAL_SOURCE_DATABASE to REMOTE_TARGET_DATABASE
  pg:reset DATABASE                                         #  Delete all data in DATABASE
  pg:unfollow REPLICA                                       #  stop a replica from following and make it a read/write database
  pg:wait [DATABASE]                                        #  monitor database creation, exit when complete
```

and furthermore...

```
Usage: heroku pg:credentials DATABASE

 Display the DATABASE credentials.

   --reset  # Reset credentials on the specified database.
```

Local testing seem to indicate that it does, indeed, give you the database user and password.

Comment: Thanks..  Can you think of another way to handle such volume?  So client B doesn't feel drained when Client A is super active?  I'm searching, and this is the best idea I have (right now)

Comment: offhand, not really... this seems like a potential solution, though, since you'll have separate databases.  My fear is a single app runs on a single "virtual" server, I don't know how Heroku treats the database instances (really AWS instances). Do they also run under the same server instance?  (I don't know)

Comment: I don't think they do, but I only base that on the way they handle the public databaase.  And that the other database plans give each DB their own Host.

Comment: Well, be sure to let me know what you find out, I'd like to know for my own benefit.  :)

Comment: Product manager of Heroku Postgres here, would love to hear a bit more on what you're trying to do for issues you may run into or that may not work as desired. Would love it if you could reach out craig at heroku.com or postgres at heroku.com

Comment: ... and that, ladies and gentlemen, is why this community is great.